[Open]Liberty MicroProfile Rest Client max upload size
Using Liberty 24.0.0.7, configured with feature microProfile-6.1 (which implies mpRestClient-3.0 and restfulWSClient-3.1), I need to send an object that contains  a byte[44MiB] inside (after serialization to JSON -- with Jackson -- maybe this increases by ~33% due to base64 encoding).
The code is:
mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper()
    .configure(...); // many jackson related configurations

response = jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder 
    .newBuilder()
    .register(new com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs.json.JacksonXmlBindJsonProvider(mapper, new Annotations[]{Annotations.JACKSON, Annotations.JAKARTA_XML_BIND}))
    .register(...)
    .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .property("dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold", "500MB")
    .build()
    .property("dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold", "500MB")
    .target("http://host:port/path/to/endpoint")
    .request()
    .property("dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold", "500MB")
    .post(jakarta.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(objectContainingBigByteArray, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
;

(see that I've spread .property("dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold", "500MB") all over in hope that one of them will be used - to no avail)
Server spits

RESTEASY005081: File limit of 50MB has been reached. The entity cannot be processed. Increase the size with the configuration property dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold

In full:

Caused by:
jakarta.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: RESTEASY005081: File limit of 50MB has been reached. The entity cannot be processed. Increase the size with the configuration property dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold. (through reference chain: ...->...)
   at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:401)
   at [internal classes]
   ... 117 more
Caused by:
jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: RESTEASY005081: File limit of 50MB has been reached. The entity cannot be processed. Increase the size with the configuration property dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold. (through reference chain: ...->...)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:365)
   at [internal classes]
   ... 131 more
Caused by:
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: RESTEASY005081: File limit of 50MB has been reached. The entity cannot be processed. Increase the size with the configuration property dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold. (through reference chain: ...->...)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.loadHttpMethod(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:491)
   at [internal classes]
   ... 141 more
Caused by:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: RESTEASY005081: File limit of 50MB has been reached. The entity cannot be processed. Increase the size with the configuration property dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold. (through reference chain: ...->...)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:402)
   at [internal classes]
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:610)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:261)
   at [internal classes]
   ... 142 more
Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: RESTEASY005081: File limit of 50MB has been reached. The entity cannot be processed. Increase the size with the configuration property dev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold.
   at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.EntityOutputStream.checkFileThreshold(EntityOutputStream.java:324)
   at [internal classes]
   ... 158 more



I made it work with -Ddev.resteasy.entity.file.threshold=500MB. Hacky, but working.
